# Google Tag Manager - Fire GA event on form field focus not getting to GA

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I am trying to create a Google Analytics event from Google Tag Manager when a user focuses on a form field. I am not able to get the event to show up in my Google Analytics account and am unsure what the cause is, I have reviewed each step and all of the code and GTM setup seem to be correct.

My Tag Manager account is working with many other tags already.

Here is the form code:

```
<div class="fancybox_form">
    <form action="http://cl.exct.net/subscribe.aspx?lid=7135602" method="post" id="subscribe">
    <p style="margin: 5px; padding: 0;">* Required fields</p>
    <div class="row">
        <p class="column large-8 small-16"><label for="">First Name</label><br>
        <input class="textfield" type="text" name="First Name" required=""></p>
        <p class="column large-8 small-16"><label for="">Last Name</label><br>
        <input class="textfield" type="text" name="Last Name" required=""></p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <p class="column large-16 small-16"><label for="">Email Address *</label><br>
        <input class="textfield" type="email" name="Email Address" required=""></p>
    </div>
    <div style="display: none;"><input class="textfield" type="text" name="Subscription Source" required="" value="WIN"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <p class="submit_container"><input class="button" type="submit"></p>
        <p class="column large-16 small-16">We will never give away your information to third parties. See our <a href="http://www.renown.org/disclaimer" target="_parent">privacy policy</a></p>
        <p><input type="hidden" name="MID" value="207548"><br>
        <input type="hidden" name="thx" value="http://r-bestmedicine.org"><br>
        <input type="hidden" name="err" value="http://r-bestmedicine.org/wp-content/themes/rhealthnews/subscribe.php"></p>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Here is the code I have in a Custom HTML tag that is fired on all pages

firing rule -

```
{{url}} matches RegEx .*
```

tag code -

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('form#subscribe :input:first').focusin(function(){
            dataLayer.push({'event':'formFieldFocus'});
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is the Classic Google Analytics Tag to push the event from the DataLayer into Google Analytics

firing rule -

```
{{event}} equals formFieldFocus
```

Tag -

```
Tag Type - Classic Google Analtyics

Web Property ID - account ID in a Macro

Track Type - Event

Category - formFieldFocus

Action - {{url}}

Label - {{referrer}}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Your form, hosted in an iframe, isn't loading jQuery. Add your jQuery library, and it should work.

Here is a [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5XF6B/).

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://bestmedicinenews.org/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.10.2'></script>
```